# Wordpress REST API _fields and _embed parameters are not working simultaneously

Tags: json, wordpress, rest

If you call the REST API using _embed parameter you will be able to get the embedded objects as "_embedded" JSON object of returned JSON as following:

```
/?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts&_embed
```

And if you use _fields parameter you can filter out the objects returned by API like:

```
/?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts&_fields=id,content,title
```

The problem is when both are_embed and _filter are used simultaneously the results returned do not contain "_embedded" JSON object no matter what combination of filter I apply. For example:

```
/?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts&_embed&_fields=id,content,title,_embedded
```

does not return "_embedded" JSON object

Worpress Version is 5.3.2 (Latest)

And pretty permalinks are not enabled so usage of "/?rest_route=" is mandatory

Comment: this is still happening in wp 5.5.1 :(

Answer (score 11):

As answered previously, it would seem the _link is necessary to figure out how to get the _embed property. But if you're like me and want to really minimize the amount of JSON that is returned, you can do the following.

Suppose you want the `wp:featuredmedia` property of `_embedded`.  Then you can request

**OPTION 1**

/wp/v2/pages?**_embed=wp:featuredmedia**&_fields=**_links.wp:featuredmedia,_embedded**

_embed => `wp:featuredmedia`

_fields => `_embedded` and `_links.wp:featuredmedia` (so that embedding will actually work)

**OPTION 2**: A slight variation that also works

/wp/v2/pages?**_embed**&_fields=**_links.wp:featuredmedia,_embedded.wp:featuredmedia**

_embed => tells us to do embedding

_fields => `_links.wp:featuredmedia,_embedded.wp:featuredmedia` (ensures we only return those)

Comment: hay, i want to access the only single field inside wp:featuredmedia. Is there any way to query only that particular field ? ie. fields=_embedded.wp:featuredmedia[0].id. When i try this it is sending complete  wp:featuredmedia.

Comment: Same question, can I only get the URL of the first featuredmedia item in specific size (smallest response)?

Comment: @VikasY did you find any result for this? I am currently facing the same challenge

Comment: @WilliamOde did you find any result for this? I am currently facing the same challenge

Answer (score 7):

You need to add `_links` to get the JSON object:

`/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_fields=id,content,title,_links,_embedded&_embed`